# Extracting CSRF Token for a DJANGO Application

Tags: regex, django, cookies, jmeter

I'm currently trying to run tests on a django web app, but the csrf token is giving me problems..

I read in a couple of places that I need to use the regex extractor to save the token that is generated, but it didn't work.

I further investigated and I saw that I needed to use a dynamic cookie value, the value is in a cookie named:

> "csrftoken"

So I tried to use ${COOKIE_csrftoken} but it didn't work.

what should I do in order to use that value of the cookie dynamically?

Comment: Hi, any news on this ? Was answer helpful ?

Answer (score 0):

Try showing in your question where the CSRF Token is located.

If in cookie, then ${COOKIE_csrftoken} will contain it only if you set in user.properties:

> CookieManager.save.cookies=true
>
> CookieManager.check.cookies=true

If in response (header or body) then check:

- http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSS/JQuery_Extractor
- http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor

You say you tried them, show how you did it.

Answer (score 0):

[How to Load Test CSRF-Protected Web Sites](http://blazemeter.com/blog/how-load-test-csrf-protected-web-sites) guide has demonstration on how CSRF protection can be bypassed for Django web application for all main post processors (RegEx, CSS, Xpath)

Hope this helps